# edx SaaS course - Which of the following are true about user stories? Select all that apply

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bdd

Hi all I'm doing the edx course and in this answer I get an error

So if any of you knows the correct answer please tell me why I get an error, if I select all options as true.

Which of the following are true about user stories? Select all that apply.

- They should describe how the application is expected to be used
- They should have business value
- They do not need to be testable
- They should be implemented across multiple iterations of the Agile lifecycle

Comment: Since this is a homework question (I've done this course also), would you be able to explain what you've tried and your reasons for it? I feel that simply giving you an answer wouldn't really help with the learning aspect, and I imagine that is the very reason you're doing the course... :-)

Comment: by the moment that I did this question, I had the question resolved, I mean, I lost this question first and only then I did this post. I understand that the meaning of the course it's learn, but if I did something wrong, I need to know why?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the SaaS textbook:

> The BDD version of requirements is **user stories, which describe how the application is expected to be used.** They are lightweight versions of requirements that are better suited to Agile. User stories help stakeholders plan and prioritize development. Thus, like BDUF, you start with requirements, but in BDD user stories take the place of design documents in BDUF.
>
> ...
>
> User stories came from the Human Computer Interface (HCI) community. They developed them
> using 3-inch by 5-inch (76 mm by 127 mm) index cards, known as “3-by-5 cards.” (We’ll see other examples of paper and pencil technology from the HCI community shortly.) These cards contain one to three sentences written in everyday nontechnical language written jointly by the customers and developers. The rationale is that paper cards are nonthreatening and easy to rearrange, thereby enhancing brainstorming and prioritizing. **The general guidelines for the user stories themselves is that they must be testable, be small enough to implement in one iteration, and have business value.**

Therefore, the answer to:

> Which of the following are true about user stories? Select all that apply.
>
> 1. They should describe how the application is expected to be used
> 2. They should have business value
> 3. They do not need to be testable
> 4. They should be implemented across multiple iterations of the Agile lifecycle

is **(1)** and **(2)**.